# What is negative_slope argument of tf.keras.layers.ReLU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, activation-function

[tf.keras.layers.ReLU](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/relu/) has `negative_slope` argument which is explained as `Float >= 0. Negative slope coefficient. Default to 0`.

```
tf.keras.layers.ReLU(
    max_value=None, 
    negative_slope=0.0, 
    threshold=0.0, 
    **kwargs
)
```

Is this to make it as Leaky ReLU? If so, is it the same with the `alpha` argument of the [tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/leaky_relu/)?

```
tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3, **kwargs)

* alpha: Float >= 0. Negative slope coefficient. Default to 0.3.
```

Comment: It says what it does right in the docs you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

> Is this to make it as Leaky ReLU?

Yes, the `negative_slope` parameter of `tf.keras.layers.ReLU` plays the same role as `alpha` does in `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU`. For example, `tf.keras.layers.ReLU(negative_slope=0.5)` and `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5)` have the same behavior.

---

Here is a visualization of their behavior:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

relu=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0.0, threshold=0.0)
relu_neg_half=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0.5, threshold=0.0)
relu_neg_1tenth=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0.1, threshold=0.0)
relu_neg_1tenth_thresh_1=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0.1, threshold=1.)
relu_neg_1tenth_thresh_2=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0.1, threshold=2.)

lrelu_alph_half=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5)
lrelu_alph_1tenth=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)

x=np.linspace(-5,5,101)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=150)
markevery=0.05
plt.plot(x, relu(x), '-o', markevery=markevery, label="ReLU | negative_slope=0.0")
plt.plot(x, relu_neg_half(x), '--s', markevery=markevery, label="ReLU | negative_slope=0.5")
plt.plot(x, relu_neg_1tenth(x), '--p', markevery=markevery, label="ReLU | negative_slope=0.1")
plt.plot(x, relu_neg_1tenth_thresh_2(x), '--d', markevery=markevery, label="ReLU | negative_slope=0.1 | threshold=2.0")

plt.plot(x, lrelu_alph_half(x), '--v', markevery=markevery*1.2, label="LeakyReLU | alpha=0.5")
plt.plot(x, lrelu_alph_1tenth(x), '--^', markevery=markevery*1.2, label="LeakyReLU | alpha=0.5")

plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.savefig('relu.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Output:
[image]